# How can I transform a DataFrame so that the headers become column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas DataFrame in this form:

[image: Data Format 1]

How can I transform this into a new DataFrame with this form:

[image: Data Format 2]

I am beginning to use Seaborn and Plotly for plotting, and it seems like they prefer data to be formatted in the second way.

Comment: You could use pandas melt : ``df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Name', value_name='Score', ignore_index=False).sort_index()`` You dont really need the `ignore_index` option; however, it could be helpful if you are strict about how you want the data to be ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try `set_index()`, `unstack()`, `renamecolumns`

```
`df.set_index('Date').unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Name',0:'Score'})`
```

**How it works**

```
df.set_index('Date')#Sets Date as index
df.set_index('Date').unstack()#Flips, melts the dataframe
d=df.set_index('Date').unstack().reset_index()# resets the datframe and allocates columns, those in index become level_suffix and attained values become 0
d.rename(columns={'level_0':'Name',0:'Score'})#renames columns
```

Comment: Wow, worked great! I need to understnad what each of those commands do I think.

Comment: See my edits. Run each step at at a time and the explanation will make sense

Answer (score 2):

Use melt function in pandas

```
df.melt(id_vars="Date", value_vars=["Andy", "Barry", "Cathy"], var_name="Name", value_name="Score")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={'level_1':'Name')
```